# Регулярное выражение: исключение в один символ

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть комбинации:

```
href="sdfsd
href="/sdcs
href="//svs
href="http:
href="https:
```

Вокруг может быть что угодно. Пытаюсь написать регулярку, чтобы к варианту `href="dscds` добавлялся слеш после кавычек, т.е. получилось `href="/asdas`.
Никак не выходит написать исключение, чтобы не затрагивались все остальные варианты.
Начал с простого, просто не трогать исключения `(href=")[^[href="\/]`, но данная конструкция хватает также первый символ после.

Как построить регулярное выражение, чтобы добавлялся один `/`, если встречается первый вариант комбинации?

**UPD**
Варианты

```
href="sdfsd
href="/sdcs
href="//svs
href="http:
href="https:
src="sdfs
src="/sdfs
src="//sdf
src="http:
src="https:
```

Если не указано http(s), то форматируем таким образом, чтобы получить абсолютную ссылку `https://domen/asdasd`

И еще вопрос, не лучше ли просто искать по условию: если после href или src нет букв с двоеточием (без конкретной проверки что за протокол подключения), то тогда и работать?

Comment: [`/href="(?!(?:\/|https?))/` replace `/`](https://regex101.com/r/kcAmS5/1/)

Comment: @Let'ssayPie благодарю, зря не оформили как ответ, в итоге ваше решение использовал, только добавил еще `(href="|src=")`, чтобы по картинкам тоже проходилась регулярка.

Comment: используйте незахватывающие группы, время сэкономите `(?:href="|src=")`, ну это так к слову, рад был помочь :)

Comment: экономия в этом деле это хорошо, спасибо)

Comment: @lets-say-pie , а как все относительные адреса в абсолютные преобразовать? слеши при обходе не могу найти и заменить.

Comment: Объясните задачу на примерах

Comment: @Let'ssayPie добавил в upd

Comment: какой язык вы используете? php? вам нужно это? https://regex101.com/r/7YGcrz/1

Comment: да, php. Не, видите, у вас в примере получаются `https://domen//sdcs` и 
`https://domen///svs` с двумя и тремя слешали вместо одного после домена.

Comment: Можете потом повторно заменить многослэшевые https://regex101.com/r/VWI3u3/1

Comment: @Let'ssayPie а за один обход это сделать не получится? Если есть http или https - не трогаем, если есть один или более слеш то убираем и подставляем слово-замену ? А то по два раза обходить один контент - не очень

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/7YGcrz/2 ?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie Только заметил, параметр ссылки (href=" и src=") удалять не нужно. Я видимо в upd не очень четко пояснил. Эта конструкция на выходе все еще должна быть в виде html

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/7YGcrz/3

Comment: @Let'ssayPie спасибо большое, теперь, вроде, как надо и все варианты учтены

Comment: Это не совсем идеально, но, если будут вопросы дополнительные, мой [`VK`](https://vk.com/id19933)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регулярное выражение можно построить так: `(href=")(?!\/|http(s)?)`, замена на `$1\` [[тестер]](https://regex101.com/r/NqhOkv/1)

В вашей регулярке вы неверно использовали набор исключений (`[^[href="\/]`), в такой конструкции будет браться любой символ, кроме указанных внутри квадратных скобок, что и происходило в вашем случае.

Comment: Спасибо за решение и за пояснение